# How to view the taken "Notes" in a new buffer in Emacs Org Mode?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I use Emacs Org mode to deal with my daily staffs. Now I use Emacs to manage some research papers. When reading the papers, I would like to take some notes as the following using the shortcut key C-c C-z or only z in the Agenda View.

When taking a new note it looks like this:
[image: C-c C-z - Taking note]

However, after completing the note taking with C-c C-c, the note is stored in the LOGBOOK under where it was taken:

[image: C-c C-c - Complete note taking]

The first problem is that the note itself is not highlight. The second problem is that, if I would like to revise this note, I do not know how to display it as when it was taken(just as in the first picture above, in a new buffer with highlight). It seems that I could only revise this note under the "Note taken on ..." line with no highlight plain text.

However, I am not pleased with this editing method since it should be as the same as the first picture, i.e., when the note was first created.

Thanks for your attention and help.

Comment: IMO, it's pretty dangerous to put headings Inside a LOGBOOK drawer. Why do you need such a structure Inside a block which is itself Inside your task?  Do you know M-x visible-mode?  That could help you somehow to visit the contents of that drawer.

Comment: Hi fniessen, thanks for your comment. I would like to take some notes when reading the research papers (or maybe books). I check the Org Mode Manual and find that I can use C-c C-z to take note. Sometimes I need to write down lots of contents so I use headings. I do not know M-x visible-mode now. I will try to find how to use it. Thanks again.

Comment: Any suggestions on how to deal with my situation (take some notes when reading books or papers)? Maybe I need to create a new .org file?

Comment: First of all, I'd like to say that anything is possible with Emacs.  With that being said, the question is how to create a solution that involves minimal coding.  For my own calendar, I create a custom *Org Agenda* buffer that shows what I want -- when I edit, I jump back to the original buffer in a narrowed view and make my edit and then when it is done, a new *Org Agenda* buffer is created based upon the same search criteria.  So perhaps part of your solution could be simply defining the area to be narrowed. I'm not seeing any quick solution here. . . .

Comment: As suggested / inferred by the comment by @fniessen, you probably want to create subtasks for your notes (instead of using the logbook approach) so that you can take advantage of the built-in highlighting, and so that the structure is searchable with the built-in utilities of org-mode.

Comment: Here is a helpful page from the manual that discusses how to search a property drawer:  http://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/advanced-searching.html

Comment: Hi @lawlist, thanks for your comments. I tried to use subtasks for my notes instead of using the logbook approach. However, when I use column view (C-c C-x C-c) to review my list of papers, the subtasks are also shown there. Perhaps I could use subtasks and at the same time shadow the levels below the papers as they should be treated as "notes".

Comment: Unwanted tasks and unwanted subtasks can be filtered out of the *Org Agenda* buffer by using the `org-agenda-skip-function`, which can be a simple regexp (e.g., *notes*) or a more complex function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to using subtasks (as discussed in the comments underneath the initial question in this thread), here is an alternative approach that places the notes at the tail end of a task **without** any blank lines between sentences.  The stock org-mode has the ability to handle this -- i.e., no modifications are required (other than keywords and priority settings)

```
** Active [#A] 0 @ Ender's Game (Orson Scott Card). :lawlist:
   DEADLINE: <2014-02-22 Sat 08:00>  SCHEDULED: <2014-02-22 Sat>
   :PROPERTIES:
   :ToodledoID: 353081871
   :ToodledoFolder: TASKS
   :Hash: 680920196368d9f25c95c09063243a7f
   :END:
• This novel was of particular interest because . . .
• Orson Scott Card has written other books . . . 
• Compare and contrast Ender's brother and sister.
```

[image: Example]
<sub>(source: [lawlist.com](http://www.lawlist.com/images/org_notes_a.png))</sub>

[image: Example]
<sub>(source: [lawlist.com](http://www.lawlist.com/images/org_notes_b.png))</sub>

Comment: Thanks, @lawlist. I still wonder do you suggest that headings should not be used in "notes"? I see in your images that you use a circle as the start of each point. Thank you.

Comment: @Tommy -- I chose a circle bullet-point so that org-mode would not be confused with a main heading or a subheading, and I wanted to draw attention to the fact that it can be a sentence or paragraph -- just no blank line(s) between sentences / paragraphs. I recommend **not** using asterisks with the notes at the tail end of a task, so as to avoid confusing org-mode -- we don't want org-mode to think that we are starting a new heading or subheading.  By not using asterisks, the notes will stick to the task above it (so long as there are no blank lines) between the notes -- sticking is important.